# Removing "Due Date" from approval workflow form

Tags: workflow, form, date-time, approval-process

Is it possible to completely remove the "Due Date" label from the approval workflow form? My customer does not use explicit due dates, and thinks it is confusing that the label for one even exists. I agree, but I've already done quite a bit of customization on the actual approval process so I'm hesitant to make tweaks in InfoPath if that's possible and if it is the only way.

Comment: You may use Jquery to hide that field. It will not change any existing logic

Comment: On the master page?

Comment: can you find the way? If JQ is used it may hide every workflow's "Due date" but I only want to hide one workflow's

Comment: You just have to check the URL. "If location.search.indexOf('template ID here') $('dueDateSelector').hide();  I used sometthing like this in a method that checked for the TemplateID query string parameter specifically.